# HTML Email : hr not works in outlook

Tags: html, css, html-table

```html
<table>
  
  <tr>
<td class="h1" colspan="12" style="font-family: 'proxima_nova_rgbold', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size: 18px;text-align:center; padding-top:10px;padding-left:30px;text-transform: uppercase;padding-bottom: 8px;padding-right:30px;line-height: 26px;color: #262626; font-weight:700; background:#f9f9f9;" align="center">

 <hr align="left" style="width: 70px; vertical-align: middle; height: 1px; background: #171717; display: inline-block;">
                        <img src="http://www.hubilo.in/images_for_links/venue_icon.png" width="25" height="25" align="center" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                        <hr align="left" style="width: 70px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; height: 1px; background: #171717;">

</td>
</tr>
  
  </table>
```

When I see this into outlook then it looks like.

left `hr` in one line

image in 2nd line and

right `hr` in new line.

How can I solve this?

Comment: You cannot use `display: inline-block` for `<hr />` like here in Outlook. You need to use `<table>`.

Comment: so you mean to say like ... one `td` , in that,  3 different tables using left, center and right alignment. right?

Comment: Exactly... Yes!

Comment: okay.. trying to do so. if not work then will inform for the same, by posting code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<table align="center" style="">
    <tr>
     <td align="left" style="width: 35px; padding: 0; margin: 0;">
      <hr style="width: 30px; border:1px solid #000000; background: #000000; ">                  
     </td>                  
     <td align="center" style="width:30px; padding: 0; margin: 0;">
       <img src="http://www.hubilo.in/images_for_links/venue_icon.png" width="25" height="25" style="vertical-align:middle;">
      </a>
     </td>
     <td align="right" style="width: 35px; padding: 0; margin: 0;background: ">
      <hr style="width: 30px; border:1px solid #000000; background: #000000; ">                 
     </td>
     
     <td align="right" style="width: 20px; padding: 0; margin: 0;">
      <span style="color:#FFFFFF; font-size:14px;"> </span>                  
     </td>
    </tr>
     </table>
```

Try this